# Ajax Control Toolkit HtmlEditorExtender: Xss Attacks

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, xss

I'm using Ajax Control Toolkit in my ASP.NET project and I have a problem with *HtmlEditorExtender* which name is **ContentHtmlEditor**. *HtmlEditorExtender* attached to *TextBox* which name is **ContentBox**.

I tried to make an XSS Atack. I edited html code with Chrome and inserted the following string:

```
<a href='javascript:alert()'>bla-bla-bla</a>
```

After post back **ContentBox.Text** equals to **<a href="javascript:alert()">bla-bla-bla</a>**.

As you can see **javascript:alert()** hasn't been removed but as I know Ajax Control Toolkit HtmlEditorExtender is using AntiXss Sanitizer.

When I call

```
ContentHtmlEditor.SanitizerProvider.GetSafeHtmlFragment("<a href='javascript:alert()'>bla-bla-bla</a>")
```

it returns:

```
<a>bla-bla-bla</a>
```

But there is a problem when I call

```
ContentHtmlEditor.SanitizerProvider.GetSafeHtmlFragment("<a href='http://somesite.com'>bla-bla-bla</a>")
```

because then it returns the same string:

```
<a>bla-bla-bla</a>
```

but I need to know the reference if the link.

What is the problem? And how can I prevent Xss Attacks on my site?